# A question about "attacks on MAC key space"

Tags: collision-resistance, mac, randomness, attack, key-size

At page 336 in "Handbook of Applied Cryptography - Menezes", I see the sentence

> For $n$-bit MAC with $t$-bit key space this requires $2^t$ MAC operations, after which one expects $1+2^{(t-n)}$ candidate keys remain".

I do not understand why is $1+2^{(t-n)}$. According to me, it must be $2^{(t-n)}-1$.

For example, in exhaustive-key search, we luckily discovered one key, so there must remain $2^{(t-n)} - 1$ candidate keys.

I read carefully this chapter but I still cannot understand this idea.
I do not know if I misunderstood the authors. Could you explain for me.

Answer (score 2):

> I read carefully this chapter but I still cannot understand this idea.

Well, we assume that there is 1 correct key and $2^t - 1$ incorrect keys.  When we test a key, the correct key will verify.  We model that MAC as a random function, that is, that an incorrect key will generate an essentially random MAC, and so would verify will probability $2^{-n}$ (as that is the probability that a random $n$ bit value being a prespecified value).

Adding these two together to get the expected mean, we get:

$$1 \cdot 1 + (2^t - 1) \cdot 2^{-n} = 1 + 2^{t-n} - 2^{-n} \approx 1 + 2^{t-n}$$

If $t \ggg n$, then this is essentially $2^{t-n}$ (and so the +1 can be ignored).  On the other hand, if (say) $t=n$, this indicates that we can expect (on average) 2 results, the correct one and a 'false hit' (and we might not get a false hit, or we might get several; the 'one' is just an average).  And, if $t \lll n$, then this expected mean is almost exactly one, that is, we find the correct key and with low probability, we might get a false hit.

> According to me, it must be $2^{(t−n)}−1$

That doesn't work; if we consider the $t \lll n$ case, that would suggest that we have a probability of getting a negative number of keys that work - obviously an absurd result.
.

Comment: Thank you Poncho. In this question I do not care about "t < n". The reason why I think 2^(t-n) - 1 is in my example. But now I can guess the author's intention. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I thank to Poncho for your kind reply. But now I have a guess like this (maybe it is not author's intention):

1. At first I think a number of keys corresponding to a number of outputs is the same. For example, if |K| = 2^3 = 8 and |Output| = 2^2 = 4 then each output will receive 2 keys. I think it is not right (of course it is not wrong). Actually, one output can receive 3 keys and another only receives 1 key. It is ok.
2. In this author's paragraph, the CONTEXT may be that another attacker precomputes all 2^t MAC operations (of course using all 2^t keys). So, each MAC-result has (1/2^t + 1/2^n) probability of success. We have 2^t MAC-results, then multiply 2^t by (1/2^t + 1/2^n) and have 1 + 2^(t - n) EXPECTED candidate-key.
3. Now, applying formular with an example t = 3 and n = 2. So, after computing all 2^3 MAC operations, attacker surely has 1 secret-key (also call target-key)  and 2 candidate-key. So in this case, given x and y, we have MAC(secret-key, x) = MAC(candidate-key-1, x) = MAC(candidate-key-2, x) = y. It means that output y corresponds to 3 keys.

That is my guess about author's intention. If anyone has different opinions, please share it to clarify the problem.

Comment: ponchos' answer is the correct one. When we talk about non-specific mac we need to model them as random function to analyze. This is the way in cryptography. Random function, random permutation, pseudo-random permutation (PRF), pseudo-random function (PRP), etc..

Comment: Yes, I know this. But I feel his explanation is not what I want. This is my opinion. If there is no other opinions, maybe I will follow my newest understanding and write it into my book

Comment: 1. argument is not correct. It is probabilstic. You can't say each have 2 key, you can save each has 2 keys with probability $p$.

Comment: 2. precompute of what? do you include all possible hashed message space?

Comment: No kelalaka: 1) I means my initial assumption is not good, although it is not wrong. Each output corresponds to 2 keys, so we have 4 outputs corresponding to 8 keys. 2) precompute all 2^t MAC (using 2^t possible keys) and hope to have expected candidate keys (Value t being large or small is not important in this context).

Comment: It doesn't do to infer peoples emotions from on topic comments. Arguments can be had, but they should remain on topic and objective.